# Removing entry from JSON file if the key matches another key in the same array using jq

Tags: json, select, key, jq

I have a JSON file that has some quiz questions, they're formatted like this:

```
{
  "ques": "What is the meaning of life?",
  "ans": "42",
  "Option1": "123",
  "Option2": "456",
  "Option3": "789",
  "Option4": "42",
}
{
  "ques": "What isn't the meaning of life?",
  "ans": "Something",
  "Option1": "something else",
  "Option2": "another thing",
  "Option3": "Something",
  "Option4": "Yet another thing",
  "Option5": "One last thing"
}
```

I want to iterate through the file, and compare the "Option X" key to the "ans" key, and if it matches, remove that line. So in the example above the output would look like this:

```
{
  "ques": "What is the meaning of life?",
  "ans": "42",
  "Option1": "123",
  "Option2": "456",
  "Option3": "789"

}
{
  "ques": "What isn't the meaning of life?",
  "ans": "Something",
  "Option1": "something else",
  "Option2": "another thing",

  "Option4": "Yet another thing",
  "Option5": "One last thing"
}
```

Comment: What you have isn't a valid JSON snippet, format it and provide one that's syntactically valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that the objects in the input stream can be processed separately,
so assuming the stream consists of valid JSON objects, a solution can be presented as a one-liner:

```
.ans as $ans | with_entries(select((.key | test("^Option")) and .value == $ans | not))
```